# Alternately style items in deeply nested lists with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I'm using react to render NESTED unordered lists from json files. I wish to display them with alternating background color each line for readability.
So something like this:

```
1 (white)
2 (gray)
    3 (white)
        4 (gray)
        5 (white)
    6 (gray)
7 (white)
```

I tried with pure CSS and it didn't seem to work, as `nth-of-type()` only checks the relative index. Just for reference, it would look like this:

```
1 (white)
2 (gray)
    1 (white)
        1 (white)
        2 (gray)
    2 (gray)
3 (white)
```

Then I tried using a counter in my recursive rendering function to determine if the current line is even or odd:

```
class Tree extends React.Component{
    renderChild = (child, count=0, key=0) => {
        //if 
        if (child.children) {
            return (
                //I need some state management so I need another component. Kind of like double recursion.
                <Subtree renderChild={this.renderChild} child={child} count={count} key={key}/>
            ); 
        }
        else if (child.name) {
            return <Node child={child} count={count} key={key}/>; 
        }
        count += 1
        return null;
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="tree">
                {this.renderChild(this.props.data)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function Subtree (props){
    // just an example of many states it's supposed to have so I have to put it in a separate component
    // collapse will trigger recount since it will change the even/odd of subsequent nodes
    const [ collapsed, setCollapsed ] = useState(false)
    return (
        <figure>
            //title for the ul. needs to be counted in the sequence as well.
            <figcaption onClick={()=>setCollapsed(!collapsed)} className={`${(props.count % 2) === 1 ? "gray field" : "field"}`}>
                {props.child.name}
            </figcaption>
            {collapsed === false
                ?
                <ul> 
                    //needs to be async here
                    {props.child.children.map((item, index) => {
                        //calls to parent to recursively render all the list
                        //add 1 counting for the title
                        //need to wait for this to finish before moving to the next item.
                        return props.renderChild(item, props.count + index + 1, uuid());
                    })}
                </ul>
                :
                null
            }
        </figure>
    ); 
}

function Node (props){
    return(
        //check if count is even or odd
        <li className={`${props.count % 2===1 ? "gray field" : "field"}`}>
            {props.child.name}
        </li>
    )
}
```

However, as you can kinda tell already, the sequence is even more messed up as the recursion kind of process nodes of the same level in sequence. So what I have is something like this:

```
1 (white)
2 (gray)
    4 (gray)
        6 (gray)
        7 (white)
    5 (white)
3 (white)
```

I know I could flatten the tree, then use a matching field to determine the even/odd. but it seems wildly inefficient both time-wise and space-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems most straightforward to do this with direct DOM manipulation in a `useEffect` (or `useLayoutEffect` if you need the synchronous call) after render.

Here is a snippet which applies a `ref` to the list container and implements a `useEffect` with a state dependency that queries and iterates over all children `li` elements with cleanup of the manipulations passed in the return callback.

```
 const ulContainerRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listItems = ulContainerRef.current.querySelectorAll('li');
    listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.classList.add(i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    });

    return () => {
      listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.classList.remove('even', 'odd');
      });
    }
  }, [data]);
```

```js
var initData = [{ id: 1, title: 'Title 1', children: [{ id: 1.1, title: 'Title  1.1' }, { id: 1.2, title: 'Title 1.2' }] }, { id: 2, title: 'Title 2', children: [{ id: 2.1, title: 'Title 2.1' }] }, { id: 3, title: 'Title 3', children: [{ id: 3.1, title: 'Title 3.1' }, { id: 2.2, title: 'Title 3.2' }] }]

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initData);
  const ulContainerRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listItems = ulContainerRef.current.querySelectorAll('li');
    listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.setAttribute('data-row', i);
      item.classList.add(i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
    });

    return () => {
      listItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.classList.remove('odd', 'even');
      });
    }
  }, [data]);

  const alterData = () => {
    let i = 1;
    setData(prevData => (
      [...prevData.slice(0, i),
      {
        ...prevData[i],
        children: [...prevData[i].children,
        {
          id: +'2.' + (prevData[i].children.length + 1),
          title: 'Title 2.' + (prevData[i].children.length + 1)
        }
        ]
      },
      ...prevData.slice(i + 1)]
    ));
  }

  return (
    <div ref={ulContainerRef}>
      <Ul list={data} />
      <button type='button' onClick={alterData}>Alter Data</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Ul = ({ list }) => {

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.length > 0 && list.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.title}
          {(item.hasOwnProperty('children') && item.children.length > 0) &&
            <Ul key={item.id + '_c'} list={item.children} />
          }
        </li>
      )
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 160px;
}

.odd::before {
  content: "(odd: " attr(data-row) ") ";
  background-color: gray;
}

.even::before {
  content: " (even: " attr(data-row) ") ";
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach works by counting all previous sibling branches (and their nested children) for each item rendered by the tree. While it will allow you to directly map your data structure inline (no flattening), the performance cost of doing this if the tree is sufficiently large and deep could make it impractical in a real life use case.

I think it really depends how often your `data` is going to be refreshed. If this is just for a navigation menu where the content does not change after the initial load, then wrapping the below in a memoised component would work fine. If you're expecting the data to change frequently, however, then I really would suggest flattening the data structure and memoising the calculation instead which can be written more efficiently, rather than trying to calculate it on the fly with each render as this approach does.

A side note: this problem really has nothing to do with asynchronous programming. It is not possible to `await` in the middle of a `map` call - the data either exists in the mapped array or it doesn't.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Level 1-1"
  },
  {
    name: "Level 1-2",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2-1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3-1"
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3-2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Level 2-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Level 1-3"
  }
];

const getSibCount = (itemArr, count = 0) => {
  itemArr.forEach((item) => {
    count += 1;
    item.children && (count += getSibCount(item.children));
  });
  return count;
};

const getClass = (count) => (count % 2 === 1 ? "grey" : "white");

function Tree({ data, count, depth }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item, i, arr) => {
        const newCount = count + getSibCount(arr.slice(0, i));

        return item.children ? (
          <li key={item.name}>
            <p style={{paddingLeft: `${depth*15}px`}} className={getClass(newCount)}>
              {newCount} {item.name}
            </p>
            <Tree data={item.children} count={newCount+1} depth={depth+1} />
          </li>
        ) : (
          <li style={{paddingLeft: `${depth*15}px`}} className={getClass(newCount)} key={item.name}>
            {newCount} {item.name}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tree data={data} count={0} depth={0} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.grey {
  background: grey;
}

.white {
  background: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```